# How to load large files with StreamReader in chunks?

Tags: c#

I am new to reading in file data using C#. I have a large text file which has data separated by commas. I would like to load this file into a `DataTable` in my application (or into domain objects), but I get an `OutOfMemoryException` when doing this. I have tried a few different ways but still the same error. It seems that in order to load the data I need to load it in chunks, process the chunk and then store it, then get the next chunk then process it etc

How can I use `StreamReader` to do this? How would I tell `StreamReader` where to read upto in the file and how does it know where to continue from to get the next chunk?

Comment: What do you do with the data? Show it to end user, store it in db..?

Comment: Are these comma separated items separated by new line?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I want to simply load large text files into a winforms app and process the data to display to the user based on their search queries etc and do the appropriate queries on the data. But the problem is allowing for large amounts of data and preventing OutOfMemory exception from occuring. I just need the data to be loaded into memory so the app can query it.

Comment: @AkashKava there is 4 colums of data separated by comma on each line.

Comment: Then do not load in memory but in a database (even a file based one like SQLite) The database have a better search capability and there are bulk load capabilities that can make loading data from a CSV file really simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Buffer Stream for chunk data read here is the code

```
private void ReadFile(string filePath)
{
    const int MAX_BUFFER = 20971520; //20MB this is the chunk size read from file
    byte[] buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER];
    int bytesRead;

    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
       {
          while ((bytesRead = bs.Read(buffer, 0, MAX_BUFFER)) != 0) //reading only 20mb chunks at a time
              {
                   //buffer contains the chunk data Treasure the moments with it . . . 
                   //modify the buffer size above to change the size of chunk . . .
              }
       }
}
```

Comment: Zain UI Abidin thank you for your reply. If I used this implementation is it possible to assign each chunk that has been read to a class level object and then return to get the next chunk and then assign the next chunk to the class level object etc and so on?

Comment: yes its possible you need to create that structure first to hold that all chunks

Comment: What's the advantage of using `BufferedStream`,  why not just `fs.Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);` ?

Comment: Well it has some more useful methods just in case if we want to use them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a paging mechanism wherein you read a specified number of lines at a time. Use the `File.ReadLines` method as it will only read lines into memory as you access them. Here is some code:

```
private static int pageNumber = 0;
const int PageSize = 10;
public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<string> page;
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while ((page = NextPage()).Any())
    {
        // Here I am simply throwing the contents into a List 
        // but you can show it in the DataTable
        lines = page.ToList();

        // Do processing
    }

    Console.Read();
}

private static IEnumerable<string> NextPage()
{
    IEnumerable<string> page = File.ReadLines("Path")
        .Skip(pageNumber * PageSize).Take(PageSize);
    pageNumber++;

    return page;
}
```